# Problem with imports jest+@vue/test-utils (vue2+nuxt)

Tags: typescript, testing, vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js

Have a problem with import @vue/test-utils ? How resolve it?

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createComponentInstance' of 'Vue.ssrUtils' as it is undefined.
[image]

I tried to change all config but I have no results

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Which config files have you updated and in what way? (I am also getting the same error)

Comment: I am using `vitest` and not `@vue/test-utils` and I am getting this exact error. Can you post what you changed in your config?

Comment: getting same error